Fancytree - How to change check boxes to select list
I am using Term Reference Fancytree Drupal module to render a vocabulary in hierarchal fashion on the content edit form. It has the below structure:
Product 1
  Feature 1
    Yes
    No
    Unknown
Product 2
  Feature 2
    Yes
    No
    Unknown
Product 3
  Feature 3
    Yes
    No
    Unknown

and so on and so for. The leaf nodes (Yes/No/Unknown) are checkboxes and I have restricted them to single select from the backend, so that content editors are able to select only one of the leaf nodes.
My client has more options coming in for the leaf nodes and therefore wants them to display as a dropdown. This does not seem to be possible to achieve in Drupal. Is this possible to do in Fancytree, may be inside some Fancytree event ?
Any help much appreciated.

The fancy tree module is specifically for displaying checkboxes, so wouldn't the simple answer be to not use the module and use the default term reference widget? You ofcourse can always do a preprocess on the widget to make it output what ever you want. There are also a multitude of other term reference widget modules available on drupal.org
